# Linux machine mvn command creates ? directory

Tags: linux, directory, home, maven

In my Linux VM, I have "?" directory created everytime I run mvn clean install command.

for ex:
cd ~/project/
where pom.xml file is present. When I run mvn command it creates "?" under project folder and tries to find .m2 repo under that. i.e. ?/.m2/repository etc.

How can I  come over this issue.

Comment: Can you publish your `pom.xml`?